# Inserting script and link tag inside the header tag

Tags: javascript, dom

Is it possible to insert/generate `<Script>` and `<Link>` tag inside the `<Header>` using only Javascript or DOM (*not JQuery*) when the page load or by just including one `<Script>` tag inside the `<Header>` and do it from there? And would still allow us to debug it and avoid duplicates if just in case we already added one similar `<Script>` or `<Link>` in the `<Header>`?

For example:

Before

```
<Header>
   <script src="Scripts/Generate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</Header>
```

After

```
<Header>
   <script src="Scripts/Generate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="Scripts/Script1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="Scripts/Script2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <link href="CSS/Css1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   <link href="CSS/Css2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</Header>
```

Any advice or answers would help me.

Comment: For those reading `<head>` is quite different from `<Header>`

Answer (score 50, accepted):

HTML:

```
<head>
    <script src="Scripts/Generate.js"></script>
</head>
```

Scripts/Generate.js:

```
if(!document.getElementById('id1')) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.id = 'id1';
    script.src = 'Scripts/Script1.js';
    document.head.appendChild(script);
}
if(!document.getElementById('id2')) {
    var link = document.createElement('link');
    link.id = 'id2';
    link.rel = 'stylesheet';
    link.href = 'CSS/Css1.cs';
    document.head.appendChild(link);
}
```

Afterwards, the HTML is:

```
 <head>
    <script src="Scripts/Generate.js"></script>
    <script id="id1" src="Scripts/Script1.js"></script>
    <link id="id2" rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/Css1.cs">
</head>
```

Comment: This is applicable for <Link> right? And is it possible to put it on an external js file and do the rest there?

Comment: (1) Yes. (2) Depends what you mean by 'it'.

Comment: For those reading; technically this does not answer the question as asked - likely due to the OP mis-typing the `<head>` tag as `<Header>`

Answer (score 10):

The easiest way is like this:

```
> document.head.innerHTML += '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />';
```

Comment: What a nice and simple solution!

Answer (score 2):

I'll presume that "duplicate" means having the same src attribute value. Note that this will only prevent the addition of a duplicate by the script, so it must be run after all other scripts have been added:

```
function conditionallyAddBySource(tagName, src) {

  tagName = tagName.toLowerCase();
  var elements = document.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
  var propToCheck = {script:'src', link: 'href'}[tagName];

  for (var i=0, iLen=elements.length; i<iLen; i++) {

    // If find a "matching" element, do nothing
    if (elements[i][propToCheck].indexOf(src) != -1) {
      return;
    }
  }

  // Otherwise, add an element of the required type
  var element = document.createElement(tagName);
  element[propToCheck] = src;
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(element);
}

conditionallyAddBySource('script', 'myJSLib.js');
```

The new element doesn't have to be added to the head, could just be written immediately using *document.write* or attached to the body (or any other element that can have child nodes other than the HTML and document element). Link elements probably should be in the head though.

#### Edit

Determine whether to check src or href depending on whether tagName is *script* or *link*.

Using Paul's suggestion of querySelector, you can use:

```
function conditionallyAddBySource(tagName, src) {

  tagName = tagName.toLowerCase();
  var propToCheck = {script:'src', link: 'href'}[tagName];
  var element = document.querySelector(tagName + '[' + propToCheck + '$="' + src + '"]');

  if (!element) {
    element = document.createElement(tagName);
    element[propToCheck] = src;
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(element);
  }
}
```

provided querySelector support is avilable (IE 8 **in standards mode** and higher, dunno about others).

Comment: If available, `document.querySelector` would be even better.

Comment: Less code, faster, more readable. Mostly the first and last reasons. `document.querySelector('script[src="Scripts/Script1.js"]')`