# How to Isolate a DIV and its contents from external CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating a chat widget that will inject a div to the body of his website. However, I don't want the div to apply CSS from default style sheet of the website.

Is there any way to isolate a div like this?

Most of the existing solutions needs to change CSS code in their website, which is not possible for me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disinherit (reset) the CSS style of a specific element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515534/disinherit-reset-the-css-style-of-a-specific-element)

Comment: Maybe use an iframe?

Comment: Please post your CSS

Comment: @FredGandt that is resetting. Resetting won't work in my case. Since there plenty of things in CSS. I want to isolate from others

Comment: @ChrisHappy Iframe is the best option so far. Bu the problem is the element that I want to insert will be always floating. If I use iframe, people can click/select elements behind it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To Isolate a div from public CSS styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10064172/how-to-isolate-a-div-from-public-css-styles)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shadow DOM with scoped CSS seems to be a good solution. However, it's still not production-ready, lacks browser support.

I ended up using [Cleanslate CSS](http://cleanslatecss.com/). It adds an extra ~20KB CSS. But do the job really well. Support all browsers too.

Answer (score 3):

## Shadow DOM

The feature(s) of the Shadow DOM `v1` *currently (constantly subject to change)* [have growing support](http://caniuse.com/#search=shadow%20dom%20v1), offering a wealth of possibilities, including **scoped CSS**.

> Shadow DOM `v0` was implemented in Chrome/Opera but other browser vendors are implementing `v1`.
> MS Edge status: [Under Consideration](http://status.modern.ie/shadowdom)
> Firefox status: [in-development](https://platform-status.mozilla.org/#shadow-dom)

From [Google Developers: Shadow DOM v1: Self-Contained Web Components](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/shadowdom):

> Hands down the most useful feature of shadow DOM is scoped CSS:
>
> - CSS selectors from the outer page don't apply inside your component.
> - Styles defined inside don't bleed out. They're scoped to the host element.
>
> CSS selectors used inside shadow DOM apply locally to your component. In practice, this means we can use common id/class names again, without worrying about conflicts elsewhere on the page. Simpler CSS selectors are a best practice inside Shadow DOM. They're also good for performance.

Below, we [`attachShadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attachShadow) to a new [`createElement( "div" )`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) to which we apply the [`style.all = "unset"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/all#allunset) to *disinherit* `all` the rules applied to the rest of the `document`'s `div`s.

We then fill our `shadow-root` with whatever content we like, and supply any styles desired, before [`appendChild( "new_div" )`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) *injects* our content into the `body`.

The result is stylistically isolated content.

```js
const new_style = document.createElement( "style" ),
      new_div = document.createElement( "div" ),
      new_p = document.createElement( "p" ),
      shadow = new_div.attachShadow( { mode: "open" } );

new_style.textContent = `p {
  padding: 1em;
  border-radius: 1em;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 15px 5px rgba( 0, 0, 0, .5 );
}`;
shadow.appendChild( new_style );

new_p.textContent = "Shadow DOM FTW \\o/";
shadow.appendChild( new_p );

new_div.style.all = "unset";
document.body.appendChild( new_div );
```

```css
body {
  background: antiquewhite;
}
div {
  background: cornflowerblue;
  border: 2px grey solid;
  border-right: 0;
  border-left: 0;
  margin: 2em;
}
p {
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS";
  margin: inherit;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p></div>
</body>
```

Comment: That looks promising. I've heard about scoped CSS. But what about the browser support?

Comment: I provided a link to caniuse.com's info at the top of the answer.

Comment: I just checked. Only supporting in Google Chrome, all others, even Firefox don't support it :(

Comment: Actually it is currently supported in Chrome, Safari, Opera, iOS Safari, Android Browser and Chrome for Android, with support in Firefox in development, and support in Edge being considered.

Answer (score -2):

im not sure if this is what you seek for. but you can inject a **link** and point it, on desired css that targets the **div** that is to be inserted to the website...

Comment: is it possible for you to inject iframe as well?

Comment: I've thought about iframe. But the problem is no element underneath iframe cannot be selected or clicked.

Comment: i try to work it around when i get home. but for now this link might give you an idea [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19673398/inserting-script-and-link-tag-inside-the-header-tag)